# How do I make my code less redundant?

Tags: python

I wanted to make this program less redudant but I could not figure out how. On one hand, there IS a pattern to this process and I feel like there is a better way to do it than manually state every single possible outcome. On the other hand, every situation is unique in its own respects. Any ideas on how to simplify this code?

```
def calculate_Winner(user, npc):


    if user == 0 and npc == 0:
        return "The computer is scissor. You are scissor too. It is a draw."
    elif user == 0 and npc == 1:
        return "The computer is rock. You are scissor. You lose"
    elif user == 0 and npc == 2:
        return "The computer is paper. You are scissor. You win (;"


    elif user == 1 and npc == 0:
        return "The computer is scissor. You are rock. You win"
    elif user == 1 and npc == 1:
        return "The computer is rock. You are rock. It is a draw."
    elif user == 1 and npc == 2:
        return "The computer is paper. You are rock. You lose."


    elif user == 2 and npc == 0:
        return "The computer is scissor. You are paper. You lose"
    elif user == 2 and npc == 1:
        return "The computer is rock. You are paper. You win"
    elif user == 2 and npc == 2:
        return "The computer is paper. You are paper too. Draw"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
move_names = ['scissor', 'rock', 'paper']
winner_strings = ["It's a draw.", "You win.", "You lose."]

def get_result_string(player_move, computer_move):
    winner = player_move - computer_move % 3
    return 'You played {}. The computer played {}. {}'.format(
            move_names[player_move],
            move_names[computer_move],
            winner_strings[winner])
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
MAP = {
    0: "scissor",
    1: "rock",
    2: "paper"
}
KILLS = {
    0: 2,
    1: 0,
    2: 1
}

def winner(user, npc):
    if user == npc:
        return "Draw."
    elif KILLS[user] == npc:
        return "You win."
    elif KILLS[npc] == user:
        return "You lose."

def calculate_Winner(user, npc):
    res = "The computer is %s. " % MAP[npc]
    res += "You are %s. " % MAP[user]
    res += winner(user, npc)
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the uniqueness of each response, while avoiding a mess of `if-else` statements, use a [Python tuple](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) as a dictionary key:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

def calculate_Winner(user, npc):
    result = {
        (0, 0) : "The computer is scissor. You are scissor too. It is a draw.",
        (0, 1) : "The computer is rock. You are scissor. You lose",
        (0, 2) : "The computer is paper. You are scissor. You win",
        (1, 0) : "The computer is scissor. You are rock. You win",
        (1, 1) : "The computer is rock. You are rock. It is a draw.",
        (1, 2) : "The computer is paper. You are rock. You lose.",
        (2, 0) : "The computer is scissor. You are paper. You lose",
        (2, 1) : "The computer is rock. You are paper. You win",
        (2, 2) : "The computer is paper. You are paper too. Draw"
        }
    return result[(user, npc)]

sys.stdout.write(calculate_Winner(0, 2) + "\n");
sys.stdout.write(calculate_Winner(2, 1) + "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def calculate_Winner(user, npc):
    rpcStr = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"]
    outcomeStr = ["It is a draw", "You lose", "You win (;"]
    winMap = [[0,1,2],[2,0,1],[1,2,0]]
    too = " too" if user == npc else ""
    return "The computer is {0}. You are {1}{2}. {3}".format(rpcStr[user], rpcStr[npc], too, outcomeStr[winMap[user][npc]])
```

This produces the exact same output as your program in the least code. An if statement is only used where it should be, and, it's very easy to change the contents of the strings.

rpcStr holds possible rock paper scissor strings.

outcomeStr holds possible outcome strings.

winMap maps the user and npc values to the index of output string that is needed, based off your if statements. For example:

```
elif user == 1 and npc == 1:
        return "The computer is rock. You are rock. It is a draw."
```

user = 1, npc = 1. When you get the element of winmap at index [1][1], you get the number 0 which is the index of outcomeStr that refers to a draw.

too holds " too" if the user and npc are equal (e.g a draw)

The last line just formats all of these values into the string. You could do this in more lines if you want it to be more readable e.g:

```
rpcUser = rpcStr[user]
rpcNpc = rpcStr[npc]
outcome = outcomeStr[winMap[user][npc]]
return "The computer is {0}. You are {1}{2}. {3}".format(rpcUser,rpcNpc,too,outcome)
```